# Json Format Error while formatting JSON file?

Tags: json

Here I'm trying to format an table field called options which can take multiple sort of options as like below

```
options : remote_ip optional string 
options : local_ip optional string 
options : peer optional string
options : in_key optional string
```

when we change option field of the table with any of the field mentioned, table will be reflected as below

```
options             : peer=s
```

Now I'm trying to change the same field using json format, and I wrote and json format file as like below. which was giving error.

```
~$ sudo ovsdb-client transact '[
"Open_vSwitch",
{
    "op": "update",
    "table": "Interface",
    "where": [["name", "==", "new_br_1"]],
    "row": {
        "options": { "peer=sai" }
     }
}]'
```

can someone help to fix this,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to name the member `"peer=sai"` because `"options"` is an object, not an array (or change it to an array). Otherwise, how would you access the value inside `{ "peer=sai" }` ?

Comment: I tried that way also still getting error
:~$ sudo ovsdb-client transact '[
    "Open_vSwitch",
    {
        "op": "update",
        "table": "Interface",
        "where": [["name", "==", "new_br_1"]],
        "row": {
            "options": "peer=sai"
         }
}]'
[{"details":"expected [\"map\", <array>]","error":"syntax error","syntax":"\"peer=sai\""}]

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: [{"details":"expected [\"map\", <array>]","error":"syntax error","syntax":"\"peer=sai\""}